# Reading multiples text file in r without the same delimiter

Tags: r, if-statement, text-files

In a folder I have like 24 *.csv files, they have the same structure and I want to create a single file. The issue is that not all the data frame are read in the same way, because for some files the sep parameter is "," and to the others ";". 
What approach should I use ? I guess probably I might put an if-statement.

Comment: `data.table::fread` is handy if you're feeling too lazy to specify delimiters and your data is reasonably well-formed. Generally the approach is to `lapply` the reading function across a vector of filenames, and `do.call(rbind, ...)` (or dplyr or data.table variants) the result.

Comment: @Ariel Silly question but is it not feasible to just just do a mass find/replace for the ';' delimiter so that all of the files are consistent? If it is just a one off thing then this may be the easiest approach. If you have to deal with it on an ongoing bases, consider encoding the files so you know what delimiter to use.

Comment: @MatthewCrews is a possibility but in the case a decimal value en in data is with " , " instead of "." That could be a problem.

Comment: @alistaire I'm a lazy person and fread worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

You can check the first line of the data frame to see if it has comma or semicolon as separator, and after call an ifelse statement:

```
L <- readLines('DataFrame', n = 1)
if (grepl(";", L)) read.csv2("DataFrame") else read.csv("DataFrame")
```

Answer (score 1):

The following simple code did the work, and very fast.

```
library(dplyr)  
library(data.table)
files <- list.files(path = "Ariel/Trips/", full.names = T)
f <- list()
for (i in 1:length(files)) {
f[[i]] <- fread(files[i], header = T, colClasses = c("factor", "factor", "factor", "factor",
                                                   "factor", "factor", "factor", "factor",
                                                   "factor", "factor", "factor", "factor",
                                                   "factor", "integer", "integer", "integer",
                                                   "factor", "numeric", "numeric", "integer",
                                                   "factor", "factor", "factor", "factor",
                                                   "factor", "factor", "factor", "factor"))
}
trip <- bind_rows(f)
fwrite(x = trip, file = "trip.csv", quote = T, na = NA, row.names = F)
```

Comment: If you plan on doing more with the data.frames than just rewriting them to a new file, `fread` creates a data.table by default, which subsets differently; if it's a concern, use its `data.table = FALSE` parameter. You could also use `data.table::rbindlist` in place of `dplyr::bind_rows` if you want to use fewer packages. Further, `lapply` will likely be quicker than a `for` loop, as it preallocates memory a bit better by default.

Comment: *... which subsets differently ..* is quite vague.. also recently this behaviour has been fixed (for the most part).. where one can use DT[, cols] to behave like a DF (assuming `cols` doesn't exist in DT), or `DT[, ..cols]` to look for `cols` (which is a char / integer vector of column names/indices) outside the scope of `DT`. See [point 2 under v1.10.0 and point 1 under v1.9.8](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md).